# Local hgignore not working

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to stop tracking changes to a subdirectory, so I [followed these instructions](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Ignore_files_in_local_working_copy_only) and added the following to .\hg\hgrc:

```
[ui]
ignore = "C:\[...\myrepo]\.hg\.hgignore"
```

where that .hgignore contains

```
syntax: glob
[subdir]/**
```

But when I run `hg status`, I get the following error:

```
skipping unreadable ignore file 'C:\[...\myrepo]\.hg\.hgignore"': invalid mode ('r') or filename
```

What does this error mean? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Are those two lines the only thing in that `.hgignore` file? If you view the whitespace are there any extra characters?

Comment: There are also lines with format `*.xxx` and `**/bin/*`. Each line ends with CR-LF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW. The instructions say to create a file ".hg/hgignore", not ".hg/.hgignore".

Are you sure you're consistently using .hgignore vs. hgignore? If I use either consistently it works correctly, but if they're inconsistent I see the error you report.

Comment: My .hgignore was consistent, and it did not work. So I used hgignore consistently, and it did. Weird.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error after I installed SourceTree.
I removed

```
[ui]
 ignore=
```

from the file **mercurial.ini** in my home directory (C:\Users\myusername) and that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, I was having the exact same issue and it is now fixed.

Comment: Sourcetree appears to initialize the value without specifying any file path so this solution is correct,  or you can also specify any path to an existing ignore file in here.